# GraphQL and Strapi Session

Tags: authentication, graphql, strapi

First of all the project is amazing, I had GraphQL working with MongoDB very quickly. Even GraphiQL with the ModHeader extension. However, I am trying to add policies to the graphQL endpoints and I am finding that `ctx.session` is always empty, even tho I am making authorized requests (via the Bearer token)

How does session work in this example? Do I need to query for the user every single time I create a request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user info is available through the `ctx.state.user` object and not the `ctx.session`. Also, feel free to take a look at the GraphQL example https://github.com/strapi/strapi-examples/tree/master/react-apollo

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see that the `ctx.state.user` indeed has the info, but how do I control how much is queried by it? it seems to include the whole document (even the nested arrays of objects)